# How to get specific values from an array in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $user_id = $row["user_id"];
    $user_name = $row["user_name"];
}

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    echo $arr;
}
```

Above code echos all the values from the `$array` how can I get a specific value of this array.
For example something like this `echo $arr[2]` (but it doesn't work)

Please mention that I'm getting some data from mysql and my purpose by asking this question is to get each value from a column separately.
Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have declare '$array', but you are not using it. Then why you declare that? And other hand '$row' itself an array no need to copy that array into another array.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to fill your array with data...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $array[]= array($row["user_id"], $row["user_name"]);
        }
```

And now you can access to your data

```
 foreach($array as $arr){
  echo $arr[0];
  echo $arr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the specific value of an array. you can get by

```
$array[2]
```

not

```
$arr[2]
```

Comment: Cooool :) Silly mistakes may happen  sometimes.!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$array = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $array[] = $row;
        }

foreach($array as $arr){
  print_r($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $user_id = $row["user_id"];
  $user_name = $row["user_name"];
  $array[] = $row;
}
```

And use `$array[2]` to get records in 2nd index.

OR

```
foreach($array as $arr){
      echo $arr[0];
      echo $arr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also useful is to use the $key=>$value in your foreach loop.

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key."->".$value."<br />";
}
```

This will list each of your array items with values and respective keys.